Why some of data does not pass to client in react?
I have an API that fetches all data completely. I tested this case by unit test and the result is ok.
API:
 [Route("/home/PackageStatus")]
 [Authorize(Roles = "Guard,User,Beneficiary,Developer,Guest,Admin")]
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult PackageStatus()
 {
     try
     {
         PackageStatusResult data = new PackageStatusResult();
         data.LastPackageData = new LastPackageData();
         data.LastCommand = new LastPackageCommand();
         data.Drives = new List<Drive>();
         data.Pumps = new List<Pump>();
         data.WorkPlans = new List<DailyWorkPlan>();
         using (SpmsTest1Context db = new SpmsTest1Context())
         {
             data.Drives = db.Drive.ToList();
             data.Pumps = db.Pump.ToList();
             data.LastPackageData = db.LastPackageData.First();
             data.Package = db.Package.First();
             data.WorkPlans = db.DailyWorkPlan.ToList();
             data.LastCommand = db.LastPackageCommand.First();
             data.Message = db.Message.First().Description;
         }

         return Ok(new JsonData()
         {
             IsSuccess = true, 
             Message = "ok", 
             Data = data
         });
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         return BadRequest(new JsonData()
         {
             IsSuccess = false,
             Message ="Error",
             Data = null
         });
     }

 }

On the other hand, I have  a component that calls this API
component :
const package2 = () => {

    const [fetchDataStatus, setfetchDataStatus] = useState("");
    const [info, setInfo] = useState({
        isSuccess: false,
        message:"",
        data: {
            drives: [],
            pumps: [],
            lastPackageData: {
                driveConnection1: false,
                coolingWater1: false,
                frequency1: 0,
                power1: 0,
                current1: 0,
                fault1: "0",
                pumpOutputPressure1: 0,
                coolingWaterTemprature1: 0,
                driveConnection2: false,
                coolingWater2: false,
                frequency2: 0,
                power2: 0,
                current2: 0,
                fault2: "0",
                pumpOutputPressure2: 0,
                coolingWaterTemprature2: 0,
                phaseControl: false
            },
            package: {

            },
            workPlans: [{
                id: 0,
                thrustPressure:0
            }],
            lastCommand: {
                isActive: false,
                workPlan: 0,
                frequency: 0,
                thrustPressure: 0,
                isActivePump1: false,
                isActivePump2: false,
                fromScada: false
            },
            message: ""
        }

    });
    useInterval(
        () => {
            setfetchDataStatus("loading");
            fetch('/home/PackageStatus')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((response) => {
                    if (!response) {
                        setfetchDataStatus("loading-lost");
                    } else {
                        setfetchDataStatus("loading-ok");
                    }
                    setInfo(response);
                    //console.log(data);
                }).catch(error => {
                    setfetchDataStatus("loading-error");
                    console.error('Fetch error:', error);
                });
            //.then((data) => {
            //    console.log(data);
            //});
        },
        500
    );


    function handleOnFocus(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        e.target.blur();
    }


    function handleWorkPlanChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void {
        throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            
        </React.Fragment>
    )

};
export default package2;

When I run Project 3 fields of data load but others do not.
lastCommand, message, and dailyWorkplan are loaded only!!!!


public class JsonData
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public object? Data { get; set; }
    public string? Message { get; set; }
}

What is the problem?

Step through your C# code with the debugger and inspect the values in data. Seems pretty obvious that some of them are null and you've got JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull or similar in your serializer settings

This is probably a duplicate of .NET Core: Remove null fields from API JSON response, just in reverse

Please include the class definition for JsonData and whatever type its Data property is

I  add a debug image. All of the data is loaded currently.

I made a mistake in the definition of the PackageStatusResult class. I add { get; set; } to items and fixed.
public class PackageStatusResult
{
    public List<Drive> ;
    public List<Pump> ;
    public LastPackageData ;
    public Package Package ;
    public List<DailyWorkPlan> WorkPlans { get; set; }
    public LastPackageCommand LastCommand { get; set; } 
    public String Message { get; set; }
}

